# Stack Notifier - a chrome extension to show new questions and inbox notifications

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, notifier

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Stack Notifier is a chrome extension which notifies you whenever new questions are available in your selected tags. This will help you to give your answers quickly before others, with no need to open several tabs and refresh; you can simply click on the notification to go straight to the question and give your answer.

**V 0.9 Released**
     *New Features*
      Link your stack exchange account and get notifications from inbox instantly.
      See list of already loaded questions in the stackNotifier Icon in the browser

#### Download

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotifier/dkicpibgdednbmlclkbcehckpfficabn

#### Platform

Google Chrome

### Contact

jayanthakgjls@gmail.com
http://codetuner.blogspot.com/

### Code

Using JavaScript and jQuery on top of Stack Exchange API v2.0.

Comment: Nice work! I especially like the desktop notification

Comment: Is there any way to select which site you get notifications from? It's a great extension but many of my tags come up in other SE sites. Is it possible to receive notifications for all tags from a specific site or two?

Comment: @Ryan, I'm really sorry. For now you will get inbox notifications form all sites but the questions (tags you subscribe) is only for StackOverflow. Planning to implement it quickly as possible.

Comment: @Jayantha It's a really cool extension, thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Nice. I am using this :)

Comment: How to enable multiple tags in the settings? even when separating the tags using `;`, it only looks at the first tag

Comment: @Ferrybig Are you sure ? I just tested with `angular;java` and worked as expected .

Comment: Oops, forgot a dot into the tag name, sorry for wasting your time, consider it a feature for auto compilation of tags (or warning for unknown tags)